# How to render HTML entities in the wishlist sidebar

Tags: magento2, sales-order, wishlist, sidebar, customer-data

I have added the © symbol to product names in Magento 2. These all appear fine on the category and product pages, however when I add an item to my wishlist the product name appears with the text & copy; rather than the actual © symbol in the wishlist sidebar widget. The same applies to the recently ordered sidebar widget. See below screenshot demonstrating this:

[image]

Does anyone know how we can convert these HTML entities to the correct symbol in the sidebar widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by changing the data-bind text to html in all the files wherever knockout is used. See below example.

> Wishlist Sidebar

Copy the file **vendor\magento\module-wishlist\view\frontend\templates\sidebar.phtml** to your custom theme.

From,

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
  <a data-bind="attr: { href: product_url }" class="product-item-link">
     <span data-bind="text: product_name"></span>
  </a>
</strong>
```

To,

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
  <a data-bind="attr: { href: product_url }" class="product-item-link">
     <span data-bind="html: product_name"></span>
  </a>
</strong>
```